# Regex : Match the two closest strings with only one occurence of another string between them

Tags: regex

I want to do a non-greedy match of two lines but that only include one occurence of another line between them.

Let me illustrate that with a log of ffprobe :

```html
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=1
pict_type=P
coded_picture_number=1
display_picture_number=0
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=1
pict_type=B
coded_picture_number=1
display_picture_number=0
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=1
pict_type=P
coded_picture_number=1
display_picture_number=0
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=1
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=1
display_picture_number=0
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=1
pict_type=P
coded_picture_number=1
display_picture_number=0
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=1
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=1
display_picture_number=0
[/FRAME]
```

This log is composed of video frames. A Frame starts by [FRAME] and end by [/FRAME].

I want to match a pict_type=B immediately followed by pict_type=I in the next frame.

Obviously `pict_type=B.*?pict_type=I` don't work here, it'll match B P I

I tried to limit the occurence of [/FRAME] to only 1

```
pict_type=B(.*?[^\[\/FRAME\]]{1})pict_type=I
```

But it matches two [/FRAME] just to reach pict_type=I

Also each video have a different number of lines so it's useless to do a regex line with \r\n repeats

What did I do wrong and how can I tell it to allow only one [/FRAME] between my two pict_type ?

Comment: It depends on how specific you want the match / pattern to be. You should prevent crossing matching `[FRAME]` before matching the next `pict_type=`  I think this pattern will give you the match https://regex101.com/r/49VQlK/1

Comment: Hmm this pattern matches everything, maybe because it's greedy. Actually I want to cross [/FRAME] and [FRAME] only once. The end frame of the B-frame and the strart of the I-frame. But I guess excluding one or both should be the same.

Comment: The pattern here https://regex101.com/r/o7AgcX/1 crosses `[/FRAME] and [FRAME] only once` right? Does it get the expected match? (Note that you should not use the `s` flag to make the dot match a newline)

Comment: Oh yes it matches exactly what I want in regex101 !
But why in Notepad++ I get 0 match ? I disable the dot matching a new line. Notepad++ doesn't have all flags settings ?

Comment: If I try it with notepad++ it works for me https://imgur.com/a/RTjpqGe

Comment: That's very strange https://i.imgur.com/JMXycmQ.png
I'll try in other regex editor, I can't explain that

Comment: Can you try it with the exact text from the link to make sure there are no spaces at the end?  https://regex101.com/r/o7AgcX/1

Comment: I just retried it with "Copy to clipboard" on regex101 and then pasted it on Notepad++ but that's the same. It perfectly works on regextester.com and freeformatter.com, strange.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Ok I just figured ! I have to remove the first / of your line as well as the /g at the end. Can you please explain me what are their role exactly in the line ?

Comment: Yes you don't have to use leading and trailing `/` in the pattern and you don't have to use `/g` for a global match. That is not required for notepad. I will post an answer with a slightly updated pattern to make it a bit more performant and some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a  pattern that matches the opening `[FRAME]` and closing `[/FRAME]` and while matching first `pict_type=B` and then the second `pict_type=I` in the next frame not crossing those boundaries using a negative lookahead `(?!`

```
\[FRAME](?:\R(?!\[/?FRAME]|pict_type).*)*+\Rpict_type=B(?:\R(?!\[/?FRAME]|pict_type).*)*+\R\[/FRAME]\R\[FRAME](?:\R(?!\[/?FRAME]|pict_type).*)*+\Rpict_type=I(?:\R(?!\[/?FRAME]|pict_type).*)*+\R\[/FRAME]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[FRAME]` Match `[FRAME]`
- `(?:\R(?!\[/?FRAME]|pict_type).*)*+` Match all lines that do not start with `[FRAME]` or `[/FRAME]` or `pict_type` using a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `*+`
- `\Rpict_type=B` Match a newline and `pict_type=B`
- `(?:\R(?!\[/?FRAME]|pict_type).*)*+` Match all lines that do not start with `[FRAME]` or `[/FRAME]` or `pict_type`
- `\R\[/FRAME]` Match a newline and match the closing `[/FRAME]`
- `\R\[FRAME]` Match a newline and match the second `[FRAME]`
- `(?:\R(?!\[/?FRAME]|pict_type).*)*+` Match all lines that do not start with `[FRAME]` or `[/FRAME]` or `pict_type`
- `\Rpict_type=I` Match a newline and match `pict_type=I`
- `(?:\R(?!\[/?FRAME]|pict_type).*)*+` Match all lines that do not start with `[FRAME]` or `[/FRAME]` or `pict_type`
- `\R\[/FRAME]` Match a newline and match `[/FRAME]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UzcduE/1)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for these explanations !